# Hide imports again inside a python module via 'del'

Tags: python, python-module, code-completion

Assuming I want to hide all implementation details of a module, and even adding an underscore [1][2] is not enough, are there practical (or pythonistic) reasons against using `del`?

**mymod/__init__.py**

```
import time
# m2.py with def tock(): ...
from . import m2 as tick

since_epoch = time.time
summer = time.daylight

# def myfn():
#     return time.ctime() # this fails of course

del time
del m2

__all__ = ['since_epoch', 'summer']
```

This way `dir(mymod)` only shows the API and `mymod.tick.tock()/since_epoch()` are usable. (*Well, almost: `mymod.tick` betrays the fact that it was once called `m2`*.)

This is useful to only show relevant suggestions in the interactive python shell, see `python3 -i -c "import mymod; print(dir(mymod))"` then `>>> mymodule.<TAB>`.

1: [Hide external modules when importing a module (e.g. regarding code-completion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16509012/hide-external-modules-when-importing-a-module-e-g-regarding-code-completion) / 2: [Python: 'Private' module in a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602110/python-private-module-in-a-package)

Comment: why convention is not enough? what are you trying to prevent your user from?

Comment: Just to hide some implementation details from new users. Explaining 20 or 30 `_impl..` in an autocomplete are a topic for the next year. And via `import mymod.m2` everything is still reachable.