# How can I prevent importing unnecessary modules from my own submodule using __all__ in Python?

Tags: python

So here's the case,
I want to import a module, say a.py. However I don't want other modules which is imported by a.py in it.
my `a.py` looks like this:

```py
__all__ = ["fuc"]

import os

def fuc():
    return 1
```

then, in the same dir i create a file called `b.py`, which is simply prints out the modules in a:

```py
import a
print(dir(a))
```

Simply running b.py gives me the output:
`['__all__', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'fuc', 'os']`, which 'os' is still in there.

Why is `__all__` not working here?

Comment: I think `__all__` limits imports only when `from a import *` syntax is used. Though, star imports are often discouraged.

Comment: Why do you want to prevent this? It doesn't *re*import the module. Module imports are cached, in any case, it just makes it available in the module's namespace. If it *really* bothers you, just don't add it to the global namespace of your module

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: 'Private' module in a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602110/python-private-module-in-a-package)