# Private class in python package

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I'm writing a python library to interface to a rest server.
I would like to be able to add classes inside the library, which I would like to be hidden once the library is installed via pip and imported into any project.

Example of the library structure:

```
.
├── my_library
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── controller
    |   ├──OtherClass.py
    |   └──Client.py
    └── models
        ├── __init__.py
        └── MyModel.py
```

Content of __init__.py in root folder.

```
from .controller.Client import Client
```

setup.py:

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='my_library',
    packages=find_packages(include=['my_library']),
    version='0.1.0',
    description='My library',
    author='Pasini Matteo',
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner'],
    license='MIT',
    tests_require=['pytest==4.4.1'],
    test_suite='tests',
)
```

what I would like not to be able to do those who use the library:

```
from my_library.controller.OtherClass import OtherClass
```

**python version >= 3.6**

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Private" (implementation) class in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/551038/private-implementation-class-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: 'Private' module in a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602110/python-private-module-in-a-package) TLDR: Python doesn't really have "true" private modules/classes/attributes. It's common practice to indicate privacy with leading underscores.